# ttkcalendar use for date range in oracle query in python pandas df

Tags: python, oracle

der sir
I successfully got all Oracle 11gr2 data to DF, but now I want to get data as per the user's given date range by using tkinter calendar date1 and date1 by ttkcalendar.
How to use these two variables in an Oracle query where saledate is between date 1 and date 2

pleaer guide me by coding

thank you in advance for your valuabel time and help

regard

Answer (score 0):

according to your code I think this should be the answer for retrieving data between two specific dates:

```
import oracledb

def get_data(date1, date2):
    connection = oracledb.connect("username", "password", "host:port/service_name")
    query = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE saledate BETWEEN TO_DATE(:date1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(:date2, 'YYYY-MM-DD')"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, {'date1': date1, 'date2': date2})
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        print(row)
        cursor.close()
    connection.close()

date1 = '2023-01-01' # you can get user date1 input here 
date2 = '2023-12-31' # you can get user date2 input here

get_data(date1, date2)
```

Comment: Two things: Don't forget to upgrade cx_Oracle; it was replaced by [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) a couple of years ago !  The second is more important: do not use an F-string `{date1}` because this is open to SQL Injection security risks.  Use bind variables - see the python-oracledb [doc](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html).

Comment: @ChristopherJones thanks for updating me with that I worked on this lib years ago, I am going to edit this really quick